# Compile all necessary files with gcc

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I’m quite new to C and the gcc compiler. I have a project where I include some other .h files. In that files there are include from more own .h files. And so on. Its a decent amount of includes.
My problem is, when I try to compile the main file with:

```
gcc -o test tests_main.c
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_waves_secure_hash_test", referenced from:
     _crypto_tests in tests_main-d1ae56.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thats because the compiler cant find the method "waves_secure_hash_test", but its in the included file:

```
#include "crypto_tests.h"
```

So, I searched a little bit and found a solution, just compile it with:

```
gcc -o test tests_main.c crypto_tests.c
```

Okay, that work for me with that two test file, where the functions are only some test prints.
For my complete project with a decent amount of includes, I can’t write down all that c files to compile... Is there a way to tell the compiler that he has to compile all needed and included files?

Comment: You can put your `gcc` command into a script so that you don't have to type it every time.  Also, for larger projects, there are build tools that help with this.  Check out CMake for example.

Comment: That's not the way the compiler works. It doesn't choose what files you need to compile, you do that. If you need it handled for you, you could use an IDE that handles building, or use some build system (make, cmake, etc.) to help you out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mixing up included files (`.h` files, header files) and source files (`.c` files). You don't have to do anything about header files, the compiler will process them automatically<sup>(1)</sup>.

You *do* have to list all source files which you want to compile.They are what defines your project. Based on your source tree organisation, you might get away with using shell pattern expansion (e.g. `*.c`) to get them, though.

For larger projects, you normally don't type the compilation command by hand, but use some project management tool, such as an IDE, a Makefile, or a buildsystem generator such as CMake.

Also note that the error you're actually getting is not a *compiler* error, it's a *linker* error. Linking is a separate step that comes after compiling. The compilation reads source files and produces object files. Linking then reads object files and produces a binary (executable or shared library) out of them.

You should also note that there is not always a 1:1 correspondence between header and source files. The classic example are libraries: you can include one or more header files which are shipped with an external library; these will provide declarations for functions implemented inside that library. This allows you to call the functions in your code. To then make these functions available to the linker (so that they can become part of your program), instruct the linker to link the library into your binary (normally via the `-l` command-line option).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> You may still need to point your compiler at directories where these header files reside, which is usually done using the `-I` command-line option.